# McEliece (FlexiProvider): How can i create KeyPair from byte array?

Tags: java, security, cryptography, public-key-encryption

I use Flexi Provider (for McEliece algorithm) to generate my public and private keys and then i saved it to file and now i need to load keypair from file, i can read file and get public key byte array and private key byte array but i don`t know how can i create KeyPair from it:
i use [flexiprovider.de](http://flexiprovider.de) for McEliece Algorithm:

**For Generating McEliece keys:**

```
import de.flexiprovider.api.keys.KeySpec;
import de.flexiprovider.core.FlexiCoreProvider;
import de.flexiprovider.pqc.FlexiPQCProvider;
import de.flexiprovider.pqc.ecc.mceliece.McElieceKeyFactory;
import de.flexiprovider.pqc.ecc.mceliece.McElieceKeyPairGenerator;

public KeyPair generateKeyPair(){
    KeyPair kp = null;
    int KeySize = 256;
    Security.addProvider(new FlexiCoreProvider());
    Security.addProvider(new FlexiPQCProvider());

    try
    {

        McElieceKeyPairGenerator mcElieceKeyPairGenerator = new McElieceKeyPairGenerator();
        mcElieceKeyPairGenerator.initialize(KeySize, new SecureRandom());
        kp = mcElieceKeyPairGenerator.generateKeyPair();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e.ToString());
    }
    return kp;
}
```

**For Load KeyPair From Byte Array:**

```
public KeyPair readKeyPair(byte[] privateKey, byte[] publicKey){
       //?? How can i create KeyPair
}
```

I try to use **McElieceKeyFactory** but i dont know how can i use it, It needs **KeySpec** (`de.flexiprovider.api.keys.KeySpec`) for generating Private Key and Public Key but `de.flexiprovider.api.keys.KeySpec` is abstract class and i can`t create new instance from it. so what should i do?

**Edit 1:**
Saved method:

```
public void writeFile(byte[] data, String fileName) throws IOException{
    FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(fileName);
    out.write(data);
    out.close();
}

public void saveKeyPair(KeyPair keyPair){
    byte[] privateKeyBytes = keyPair.getPrivate().getEncoded();
    byte[] publicKeyBytes = keyPair.getPublic().getEncoded();

    writeFile(privateKeyBytes,"Private.key");
    writeFile(publicKeyBytes,"Public.key");
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try the following code. Also notice that I don't directly use the key pair generator and key factory *implemetations*.

```
KeyPairGenerator mcElieceKeyPairGenerator = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("McEliece");
mcElieceKeyPairGenerator.initialize(keysize, new SecureRandom());
kp = mcElieceKeyPairGenerator.generateKeyPair();

final byte[] publicKeyData = kp.getPublic().getEncoded(); 
X509EncodedKeySpec publicKeySpec = new X509EncodedKeySpec(publicKeyData);
KeyFactory mcElieceKeyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance("McEliece");
PublicKey regeneratedPublicKey = mcElieceKeyFactory.generatePublic(publicKeySpec);

final byte[] privateKeyData = kp.getPrivate().getEncoded();
PKCS8EncodedKeySpec privateKeySpec = new PKCS8EncodedKeySpec(privateKeyData);
PrivateKey regeneratedPrivateKey = mcElieceKeyFactory.generatePrivate(privateKeySpec);
```

Comment: tanx dude, for try to help me, i saved my KePair using `kepair.getPrivateKey().getEncode()`, it return byte array and then i saved it in file and same for public key but how can i make key pairs from these bytes? i can using google, and i saw McEliecePublicKeySpec or McEliecePrivateKeySpec before but i have not any Parameters of create instance of McEliecePrivateKeySpec or McEliecePublicKeySpec, i have keys in byte and i don`t need to generate it again from parameters, so if you have better idea, please edit your answer and give me help, tanx again

Comment: Have you tried `X509EncodedKeySpec` for the public key? The flexiprovider tells you in the [`getEncoded()`](http://www.flexiprovider.de/javadoc/flexiprovider/docs/de/flexiprovider/api/keys/PublicKey.html#getEncoded()) that it returns this specific format... And similarly `PKCS8EncodedKeySpec` for the private key... Do use the key factory you are currently using...

Comment: Downloaded the provider to check this answer, does compile and run here without issue...sorry to lead you in the wrong directly initially, missed the `getEncoded()` call...

Comment: its works fine with magic classes `X509EncodedKeySpec, PKCS8EncodedKeySpec` .. tanx owlstead